# JSF Session bean is null and unable to save the current user object

Tags: jsf, nullpointerexception, managed-bean, managed-property

I am trying create a simple login page, where the username and password is checked against the data stored in the database (using hibernate). When successfully authenticating the user, I want to store the ID or the user object in the session bean.

For some reason a nullpointerexception is thrown when the user object is assigned to the session bean. As far as I have seen, the session Bean (userHolder) is null and therefore I it doesn't allow the object to be stored.
The error occurs on my UserDAO.java file on the following line,

```
userHolder.setCurrentUser(user);
```

Appreciate if someone could point me on the right direction.

**JRE System Library - Java SE 8 [1.8.0_40]
WildFly 8.x
JSF v2.2**

Entire code can be seen below.

**userHolder.java**

```
package domain;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserHolder implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private User currentUser;

    public User getCurrentUser() {
        return currentUser;
    }
    public void setCurrentUser(User currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }


}
```

**UserDAO.java**

```
package domain;

import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

@ManagedBean 
@RequestScoped
public class UserDAO {
     @ManagedProperty("#{userHolder}")
        private UserHolder userHolder;

        @PostConstruct
        public void Dummy() {
            User user = userHolder.getCurrentUser();
        }

        public UserHolder getUserHolder() {
            return userHolder;
        }

        public void setUserHolder(UserHolder userHolder) {
            this.userHolder = userHolder;
        }


    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

    public void save(User user){
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
    public Integer getId (){
        String hql = "select max(user.id) from User user";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Integer> results = query.list();
        Integer userId = 1;
                if (results.get(0) != null ) {
               userId = results.get(0) + 1;
                }
                return userId;
    }

    public String authenticate (String username,String password){
        String hql = "FROM User user WHERE user.username = '" + username+ "' AND user.password = '" + password+ "'";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<User> results = query.list();
        java.util.Iterator<User> iter = results.iterator();

        if(results.isEmpty()){
            return "error";
        }
        else{
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                User user = iter.next();
                System.out.println("Person: \"" + user.getFirstName() + "\", " + user.getLastName());
                userHolder.setCurrentUser(user);
                System.out.println(userHolder);
            }
            return "success";
        }       

    }
}
```

**LoginRequest.java**

```
package domain;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;


@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped

public class LoginRequest {
    private String username;
    private String password;


    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String login() {

        UserDAO userDao = new UserDAO();
        String response = userDao.authenticate(username, password);

        if (response.equals("success")){
            System.out.println("success");
            return "loggedIn";
        }else{
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
                    FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Login failed", null));
        }
        return null;
   }
}
```

**login.xhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Web Shop - The Three Bears</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:messages/>
        <h3>User Login Form</h3>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputLabel value="Username:" />
            <h:inputText value="#{loginRequest.username}" /> <br />
            <h:outputLabel value="Password" />
            <h:inputSecret value="#{loginRequest.password}" /> <br />
            <h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginRequest.login}" />
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error console**

```
10:38:16,634 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (default task-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
10:38:16,760 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] (default task-3) HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
10:38:16,764 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (default task-3) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
10:38:17,014 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (default task-3) HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
10:38:17,015 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (default task-3) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
10:38:17,017 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (default task-3) HHH000396: Updating schema
10:38:17,038 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (default task-3) HHH000261: Table found: webshopstudent.User
10:38:17,038 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (default task-3) HHH000037: Columns: [id, username, lastname, firstname, password]
10:38:17,038 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (default task-3) HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
10:38:17,039 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (default task-3) HHH000126: Indexes: [primary]
10:38:17,039 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (default task-3) HHH000232: Schema update complete
10:38:17,197 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Hibernate: select user0_.ID as ID1_0_, user0_.FIRSTNAME as FIRSTNAM2_0_, user0_.LASTNAME as LASTNAME3_0_, user0_.PASSWORD as PASSWORD4_0_, user0_.USERNAME as USERNAME5_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.USERNAME='avizzzy' and user0_.PASSWORD='avizzzy'
10:38:17,236 INFO  [stdout] (default task-3) Person: "Vinod", Sudharshan
10:38:17,236 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-3) #{loginRequest.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException: #{loginRequest.login}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at domain.UserDAO.authenticate(UserDAO.java:66) [classes:]
    at domain.LoginRequest.login(LoginRequest.java:32) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    ... 34 more

10:38:17,243 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /WebShopStudentVersion/login.xhtml: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at domain.UserDAO.authenticate(UserDAO.java:66) [classes:]
    at domain.LoginRequest.login(LoginRequest.java:32) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:292) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-3.0.1-b05.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.2.6.Final.jar:2014-10-03 10:05]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.8-jbossorg-1.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.8.jar:2.2.8]
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: At what point is `authenticate` called?

Comment: @kolossus, It's called from the LoginRequest class. I have updated the main post to add the code from LoginRequest.java and the login.xtml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be an issue with the annotations you are using.
Assuming that you are using CDI you should change the annotations that you are using:

Try:

- `javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped` instead of `javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;`
- `javax.inject.Named` instead of `javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean`
- `javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped` instead of `javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped`
- `javax.inject.Inject` instead of `javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty`

This setup works for me with JEE7/Glassfish, so if this does not work you can narrow the problem further

[Have a look here for more details](http://germanescobar.net/2010/04/4-areas-of-possible-confusion-in-jee6.html)

Comment: Just updated the post with the versions I use. I do use JSF v2.2, so changed the annotation import from both classes to `import javax.enterprise.context.*`.  But still get the  `java.lang.NullPointerException: javax.faces.FacesException`

Comment: updated the answer with more details. Note that I have tested this with latest Glassfish using CDI. I do not have experience with Wildfly, but this at least should narrow the problem

Comment: I updated my code as you've suggested. But still get the exact same error. I debugged the code by placing a line break point on `userHolder.setCurrentUser(user);` but the variable `userHolder` has a value null.

Comment: I have also added the error log, if it helps you to see what I am missing or doing wrong.

Comment: Can't think of anything else. From what you say, the injection fails. I would doublecheck that new code is properly deployed and that I didn't miss any of the annotations. The next step would be to try accessing the session bean from the JSF page itself to make sure that it has been initialized. Following that, I would try a simple example and if it did not work, I would try it on another app server. Note that a lightweight container might not be JEE7 complaint, but I cannot verify this.

Comment: Hi @Ioannis, you were right about having to update all those annotations. I made a mistake by defining a private variable as `@Current`, where as `@Current` is not supported any longer and I had to use @Inject. The worse part is that since @Current didn't have a import statement, Eclipse let me create a manual annotation. This made sure that no error was shown for `@Current`, so I couldn't spot what the issue. Thanks for the help and pointing me at  the right direction. Cheers